# How do I store text file into an array and then display line by line on demand (through key binding)

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm a teacher with a very limited programming background struggling with C# to make some videos for my students who are pretty much anxious and depressed during the pandemic. I'm using GTA5 as my platform because it is easy to customize, has amazing locations, hundreds of potential characters, and supports voice as well (I'm using Amazon Polly). Needlessly to say I'm stripping out all the violence and swearing.

The roadblock I'm hitting, and there isn't any support to speak of on any GTA forums or Mods forums, is how to display lines of text on the screen on demand. I've managed to do this hardcoded, but I would prefer to read this from a text file and display line by line, not by a timer, but on demand with a single key binding, ideally with the ability to go back and forth (but line by line).

A friend of mine who works for a AAA gaming company, doesn't know the GTA5 environment but said the solution would be to read the lines into an array. Unfortunately I don't have that programming knowledge, so I'm stuck at this point. Here is my code. Right now it will only display the last line of a test text file. Code is put together from Microsoft documentation and random GTA forum posts. Again, I can do this manually through multiple hardcoded lines of text, each with a key bind, but that's totally impractical. Need text file, one keybinding  and a way go line by line (and ideally backwards)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GTA;
using GTA.Math;
using GTA.Native;

namespace TextDrawing
{
    public class TextDraw : Script
    {
        public static string TextString { get; set; }
        
        public TextDraw()
        {
            Tick += onTick;
            Interval = 0;
            KeyDown += Basics_KeyDown;

        }

        private void onTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           if (Game.IsLoading) return;
           DrawText();
        }


        private void DrawText()
        {
            var pos = new Point(100, 100);
          //  TextString = "Default Start Screen goes here if you want it on load";
            var Text4Screen = new GTA.UI.TextElement(TextString, pos, 0.35f, Color.White, GTA.UI.Font.ChaletLondon, GTA.UI.Alignment.Left, true, false, 1000); //last parameter is wrap width
            Text4Screen.Enabled = true;
            Text4Screen.Draw();
            
        }
        private void Basics_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad7) //code replace code in Basics_Tick
            {
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines
               (@"C:\Users\UserName\test.txt");
                foreach (string line in lines)
                    

                {
               
                    TextString = line; //"Lesson 1 Topics Today. \n\n Part 1. Drawing Text on Screen \n\n Part 2. Customizations" + TextString2;
                    DrawText();
        
               
                }
            }
    

        }
     

    }
}
```

Comment: Create a member variable: `int index = 0;` Then use that to figure out which line to print in `DrawText()`: `TextString = lines[index++];`. You also need to make `lines` a member variable.

Comment: What does "display line by line" mean? I'm wondering how you see the relationship between your c# app and GTA working.. Does your c# have to e.g. "press some keys" and it causes a GTA character to speak the words? Are you expecting C# to "type" into some chatbox in GTA, like a human user would?

Comment: Off topic: your backstory isn't required. Just the code and a description of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for providing backstory, didn't mean to offend anyone. GTA5 has hooks supporting coding in C++, lua, vb.dotnet, etc., but mostly c# dot.net. It has its own functions. I apologize for lack of clarity. The concept is to read text, which in essence is a lesson, from file rather than hard coding text as strings. By pressing a key, for example numpad 7, the first line of the text file would be displayed at the coordinates in the code on the screen of the GTA5 game. The next time the same key is pressed, the second line of the text file would be displayed. Going forward, and ideally back too.

Comment: Sorry if that came out rude. I wasn't offended. Just some friendly advice.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. I don't want to figure out which line to display on the GTA5 screen. I want to go through every single line, sequentially, by pressing a key. First press displays line 1 and so on. Ideally, perhaps through a different key binding, I could go backwards, but always line by line. Never show line 15 for example, not that it would be a bad thing, but this will not be interactive, it will be a video and I will be the one pressing the keys but only during the making of the video.

Comment: See my answer below. I believe that is what is should do. Except the backwards part, but that should be easy to add.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. No worries, didn't take it as rude. Only gave the backstory to clarify I'm not a computer science student asking you to do my homework. Lol.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. So if i understand you correctly, I will just need to increment the index, for example index+1 in the loop? Also, I apologize for not knowing this, but is a member variable the same as declaring a public static one? Anyway I'll google, it try to figure it out, and report back. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: In my code you'll see `string textString = lines[index++];` The `++` increments by 1. Note: there is no loop. The draw text function is only called when a key press event happens.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. Got it. Sounds like a plan. Off to Visual Studio. Will report back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with GTA scripting, but maybe create a member variable: `int index = 0;` Then use that to figure out which line to print in `DrawText()`:

```
namespace TextDrawing
{
    public class TextDraw : Script
    {
        // The lines of the text file
        string [] lines;
        // The index of the next line to print
        int index = 0;
        
        public TextDraw()
        {
            Tick += onTick;
            Interval = 0;
            KeyDown += Basics_KeyDown;
            // Read the file here
            lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\UserName\test.txt");
        }

        private void onTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (0 == lines.Length || Game.IsLoading) return;
            DrawText();
        }

        private void DrawText()
        {
            var pos = new Point(100, 100);
            // Get next line
            string textString = lines[index];
            var Text4Screen = new GTA.UI.TextElement(textString, pos, 0.35f, Color.White, GTA.UI.Font.ChaletLondon, GTA.UI.Alignment.Left, true, false, 1000);             
            Text4Screen.Enabled = true;
            Text4Screen.Draw();
        }

        private void Basics_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // When Keys.NumPad7 is pressed, show next line
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad7)
            {
                if (index < lines.Length - 1) index++;
            }
            // When Keys.NumPad8 is pressed, show previous line
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad8)
            {
                if (index > 0) index--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated to use `onTick` and go backwards. Apparently the `onTick` is needed to continually redraw the text. Being unfamiliar with the GTA API, I did not realize that.

Comment: This works perfectly with the added benefit of going backwards which I wasn't sure how to approach. Your solution and help is greatly appreciated. I should have mentioned the ontick event which you correctly surmised updates the game frames, redrawing the text. The interval is in milliseconds (but set to 0). GTA5 has its own native functions, from decompiled scripts, but there is also a library scripthook5dotnet which puts wrappers around these functions. THANKS TO YOU BOTH! This is off topic, but stay safe and healthy. And yes, I'll take C# course in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. But a few key code changes should make it work.

1. Create two class-level variables, an array to keep all the read files and an int index to keep track of your current index.
2. Create a function to read and invoke that in the constructor (ideally it should not be read in the constructor but rather triggered by external user action. But let's keep it simple for now).
3. In the key press event, update the string and increase the index. Your code is currently not working because you are iterating through the entire array and assigning text to a single variable. So only the last value is remains on screen.

> ```
>  public class TextDraw : Script
>     {
>         public static string TextString { get; set; }
>         public string[] AllLines { get; set; }
>         public int currentIndex = 0;
>         public TextDraw()
>         {
>             Tick += onTick;
>             Interval = 0;
>             KeyDown += Basics_KeyDown;
>             ReadAllLines();  ///Ideally not here. But should work still.
>         }
>         private void ReadAllLines()
>         {
>             AllLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines                        (@"C:\Users\UserName\test.txt");
>     }
>
>     private void onTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         if (Game.IsLoading) return;
>         DrawText();
>     }
>
>
>     private void DrawText()
>     {
>         var pos = new Point(100, 100);
>         //  TextString = "Default Start Screen goes here if you want it on load";
>         var Text4Screen = new GTA.UI.TextElement(TextString, pos, 0.35f, Color.White, GTA.UI.Font.ChaletLondon, GTA.UI.Alignment.Left, true, false, 1000); //last parameter is wrap width
>         Text4Screen.Enabled = true;
>         Text4Screen.Draw();
>
>     }
>     private void Basics_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad7) //code replace code in Basics_Tick
>         {
>             if (currentIndex >= 0 && currentIndex < AllLines.Length)
>             {
>                 TextString = AllLines[currentIndex];
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 TextString = "The End";
>             }
>             currentIndex++;
>             DrawText();
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you all so much! It works. I'll figure out how to go backwards myself.

Comment: How do I do a line break here! lol.  @Johnny, code work but lines were only flashed on.

Comment: with your solution the lines remained on display until the next press. Again THANKS to both of you.

Comment: I was very happy to see the dedication you have for your profession :)

Comment: @aliciawindsor Apparently the onTick is needed to continually redraw the text. I have updated my answer accordingly.